# How do I create a dynamic join statement in a method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have an array of tables that I need to join:

```
tables = ["users","cars"]
```

But, I am trying to do joins on these:

```
joins(:users,:cars)
```

The code is not working. In my model I have a definition where I pass in the tables:

```
def conditions(tables)
    joins(tables.map { |t| t.to_sym }.join(","))
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This method would be a good candidate for the splat operator.

`.joins` takes an undefined number of arguments, so what you need is a way to deconstruct the array into arguments. `.join(",")` will turn it into a string, which is not what it expects. However, this: `joins(*tables.map(&:to_sym))` should do the trick.

Comment: So, I am still learning rails, but is it always required in rails to join a table, even if the model has the association declared? For example, the model I am using here already has the has_one :user, :through => :car and belongs_to :car in place, I guess i am just confused why these associated tables are required when the model already has the associations in place

Comment: No, the `.joins` relation is used to return the records for which the stated associations are actually present, i.e. not `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

The method you wrote is passing a string `"users, cars"`, which is going to raise error. Use the splat(`*`) operator:

```
def conditions(tables)
  joins *tables.map(&:to_sym)
end
```

http://endofline.wordpress.com/2011/01/21/the-strange-ruby-splat/